# How to parse and iterate prototype methods with Uglify.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, uglifyjs2

I 'd like to parse some JavasScript code to list all methods for a given "class" using uglify js 2. In my case the TreeWalker returns a node with `name : null` and there is no information that allow conclusions to parent.

Does anyone know a different approach?
I expected something like `name : "Test.method_name"`
So far I tryied the folowing...

parsetests.js

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js2");
var util = require("util");
var code = require("fs").readFileSync("test.js").toString();
var toplevel = UglifyJS.parse(code);
var log = function(obj, depth) {
    console.log(util.inspect(obj, showHidden=false, depth, colorize=true));
};
var toplevel = UglifyJS.parse(code);
var walker = new UglifyJS.TreeWalker(function(node){
    if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Function ) {
        log(node, 2);        
    }
});
toplevel.walk(walker);
```

test.js

```
function Test(argument1) {
    var m = argument1 + "test";
    return this;
}


Test.prototype.method_name = function(first_argument) {
    // body...
    return "a";
};
```

UglifyJS.TreeWalker node:

```
{ end:
   { file: null,
     comments_before: [],
     nlb: true,
     endpos: 156,
     pos: 155,
     col: 0,
     line: 10,
     value: '}',
     type: 'punc' },
  start:
   { file: null,
     comments_before: [],
     nlb: false,
     endpos: 111,
     pos: 103,
     col: 29,
     line: 7,
     value: 'function',
     type: 'keyword' },
  body:
   [ { end: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       value: [Object] } ],
  cname: undefined,
  enclosed: undefined,
  parent_scope: undefined,
  uses_eval: undefined,
  uses_with: undefined,
  functions: undefined,
  variables: undefined,
  directives: undefined,
  uses_arguments: undefined,
  argnames:
   [ { end: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       thedef: undefined,
       name: 'first_argument',
       scope: undefined,
       init: undefined } ],
  name: null }
```

Comment: Do you exclusively want to use uglify-js2 or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: This won't be as easy as you think as you'd need to track dynamic allocation through other methods, unless you know they were done a certain way. I think [Tern](http://ternjs.net) does a bit of analysis like this but I'm not sure whether that's suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a script able to parse and identify those syntax. I open sourced it at https://github.com/s-a/deep-js.

Currently it covers a bunch of use cases described at https://github.com/s-a/deep-js/blob/3c1e52b75be197ff19a5530d011e999416e21afd/use-case-main.js
And tested with https://github.com/s-a/deep-js/tree/3c1e52b75be197ff19a5530d011e999416e21afd/test. You can see the results at https://travis-ci.org/s-a/deep-js/builds/58511486. 
Current code state is limited. For example `this` could currently not resolved if used over another var like `self`. Deep nested assignments and namespaces are another problem. However so far it is stable if code complexity is not too high.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the function does not have a name, it is assigned to a property which has a name. You must name your function as follows:

```
Test.prototype.method_name = function method_name(first_argument) {
    // body...
    return "a";
};
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what the question is asking for. The OP is looking to statically determine the methods that a constructor has, not find the name of a function during debugging.